How to make a code to recognize if a pattern is inside a string only with ? and * in autoit
How to make a code to recognize if a pattern is inside a string only with ? and * in autoit.
Examples
function("string","pattern",1 = sensitive\0 = no sensitive)
function("hello whale","?ello *",1) = true return 1
function("hello whale","?ello w?al*",1) = true return 1

...
The problem is that I can't use regular expressions because the characters are taken as an expression. I would need to make a code that is as fast as possible since I have to make many comparisons. Thanks
Example:
Func iswm($string,$pattern,$s)

  if Not $s then

    $string = StringLower($string)
    $pattern = StringLower($pattern)

  EndIf

  If StringRegExp($string,"^" & StringReplace(stringreplace($pattern,"*","(.*)") & "$","?","(.)")) = 1 Then return 1

EndFunc

The problem is that the $pattern may contain characters that I don't want to be evaluated just * and ?

Your method seems a bit complicated.
I think, using REGEX patterns work just fine (function2), but if for whatever reason you can't use them, function works with your wildcards ? and *:
; function("string","pattern",1 = sensitive\0 = no sensitive)
ConsoleWrite(function("Hello whaLe", "?ello *", 1) & @CRLF)
ConsoleWrite(function("hEllo whaLe", "?ello w?al*", 1) & @CRLF)

ConsoleWrite(function2("Hello Whale", ".ello .*", 1) & @CRLF)
ConsoleWrite(function2("Hello whAle", "^.ello w.al.*$", 1) & @CRLF)


Func function($string, $pattern, $case) ; using your wildcards
    $pattern = StringReplace($pattern, "?", ".")
    StringReplace($pattern, "*", ".*")
    If $case = 1 Then $case = "(?i)"
    $y = StringRegExp($string, $case & $pattern, 0)
    ; ConsoleWrite("DBG: " & $string & " / " & $pattern & " / " & $case & " = " & $y & @CRLF)
    Return $y
EndFunc   ;==>function

Func function2($string, $pattern, $case) ; using standard REGEX wildcards
    If $case = 1 Then $case = "(?i)"
    $y = StringRegExp($string, $case & "^" & $pattern & "$", 0)
    ; ConsoleWrite("DBG: " & $string & " / " & $pattern & " / " & $case & " = " & $y & @CRLF)
    Return $y
EndFunc   ;==>function2


The problem is that I only want the regex pattern to work with * and ? for example:
function("hello whale^ tal","whale^",0) return 0
and it should return 1
I would only have to evaluate the two wildcards * and ? and treat the rest of the characters as a string
I know it's complicated but I don't know how to do it.

You want to change REGEX rules? Then you have to program your own version. That won't be fast. Not at all. Again: if you use a proper REGEX pattern, it should work. Because REGEX treats ^  as "start of string", you have to escape it to be treated as literal character: `"whale^"
